# RSS feed with nested items, what is the proper way?

Tags: rss, nested

I have a product that has multiple variations. I would like, in an RSS feed, to show this as a nested items option, but I don't know if this is valid or not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:s="http://example.com/s">
    <channel>
        <title>Examle RSS</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com/</link>
        <description>Example Product Feed</description>
        <language>en-us</language>

        <item>
             <title>My Product</title>
             <description>An amazing item!</description>
             <item>
                 <title>AS-435</title>
                 <s:price>$34.00</s:price>
             </item>
        </item>

    </channel>
</rss>
```

If this isn't valid what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not valid, but it's a very interesting idea.

You'd have to put the inner items in a new namespace.

And keep in mind that no one else will understand what you're doing.

Comment: Well it is for a specific client who needs all that info, and they will be parsing it themselves, so I'm inclined to believe that it may work for my purposes...

Comment: Here's what that namespace would look like. http://rsscloud.org/namespace.html I was trying this out as an idea for a product that I didn't ship. But this is how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The rss schema definition for an <item> does not include the option for another <item> sub-element. (http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)

If the data only needs to be consumed only by your client's proprietary parser, why not drop the RSS schema and use a custom one?

Otherwise, if it would be of some benefit to be compatible with feed readers, why not create a feed for each type of item, web 2.0 style? For example, one for product lines, one for product models and one for product makes. Better make the feeds query-able, and identify each item with a unique id.

I in fact located this thread to promote my agenda.